# django - catch multiple exceptions

Tags: python, django, exception

I have this view function:

```
def forum(request):
qs = Forum.objects.all()
try:
    f = Forum.objects.filter().order_by('-id')[0] <------------problem
    return render_to_response("forum.html",{'qs':qs,'f':f},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
except Forum.DoesNotExist or IndexError:
    return render_to_response("forum.html",{'qs':qs},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but it is still giving following error for the problem line above:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

is my code fine? can i catch multiple exceptions in this way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can catch multiple exceptions in this manner

```
try:
    ...
except (Forum.DoesNotExist, IndexError) as e:
   ...
```

Comment: Why is there no catch-all for this? Specifying each exception is stupid.

Comment: @AlxVallejo You don't have to catch a specific exception at all. It's common practice to specify the exception for better handling, but you can simply say: `except Exception, error:` and call it a day.

Answer (score 18):

When you have this in your code:

```
except Forum.DoesNotExist or IndexError:
```

It's actually evaluated as this:

```
except (Forum.DoesNotExist or IndexError):
```

where the bit in parentheses is an evaluated expression. Since `or` returns the first of its arguments if it's truthy (which a class is), that's actually equivalent to merely:

```
except Forum.DoesNotExist:
```

---

If you want to actually catch multiple different types of exceptions, you'd instead use a tuple:

```
except (Forum.DoesNotExist, IndexError):
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to log/handle each exception, then you can do it like this.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    your code here
except KeyError:
    logger.error('You have key error')
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    logger.error('Object does not exist error')
```